# trouble using $.ajax() with async : false calling rest service

Tags: jquery, rest

I have the following piece of code :

```
$.ajax({
     url:    'http://localhost:8080/App/game/leo/create',
     type: 'PUT',
     async:   false,
     success: function(result) {
                  console.log(result);
              },
     error: function(result) {
                 console.log('Error found');
                 console.log(result);
              },
     complete: function() {
                 console.log('call completed');
     }

});
```

and I would expect the program to enter  the  `success`section , but  enters `error` section code and logs "Error found" and the object with the response I'm expecting. I know that the URL is correct and actually returns a 200 OK code and a string. Any ideas ?

Comment: if you can, then remove async:false, and try

Comment: Check the wire-are you sure? I'm a little skeptical.

Comment: btw. isnt async false and ajax a contradiction in terms ? ^^

Comment: I need it sync, because the rest of the code depends on the result of this rest call

Comment: Does the resource support a PUT request? Are you requesting it from the same domain and port, so it's not the same origin policy that is the problem? What content type does the response have? Perhaps jQUery tries to parse it as something that it's not.

Comment: Please read the doco for the `error` callback arguments. FYI, it takes 3. Also, it wouldn't enter the error callback if the response code was 200

Comment: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

Comment: no, the javascript is in one port, the rest service  is in another port, I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin ,and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers  to the response.

Comment: Also, check your browser's *Net* console. You should be able to see all network traffic (requests and responses) there. Make sure to check the error console too

Comment: @Phil I added the other two arguments to the error callback , ans this  was logged "parsererror" "SyntaxError {}" , so I suspect  the json returned is not right.

Comment: @Leo Ah, I stand corrected. It will enter the *error* callback for a parse error. Maybe try running the response through http://jsonlint.com/. You could also try setting `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` settings just in case your service isn't setting the correct response type

Comment: @johnSmith Nothing wrong with making the request synchronous. The *X* in *AJAX* used to stand for *XML* but that rarely applies these days ;)

Comment: @Phil and what stands the A for ? Isnt it asynchronous, well i know that its possible, ehy would there be this option.. but i think its a contradiction in terms

Comment: @Phil, yes it was bad json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments , I've found the problem. It was bad formatted json, I was generating in the REST service  something like `{'id': '633ac368-b595-4552-bb01-2e23f99ee132'}`

which to my sight it was good json format , but it was not, the right way is

`{"id": "633ac368-b595-4552-bb01-2e23f99ee132"}`  ( double quotes instead of single quotes )

Thanks to all for commenting.